# $watch breaks ng-model binding (angularJS)

Tags: angularjs

I have two textboxes with different ng-model. I am populating second textbox by using $watch on first textbox, however when i modify second textbox and save the changes, same value gets saved in both textboxes. I want to be able to save the updated value of the second textbox. If I do not use $watch, both textboxes are getting right values. So, I think $watch is breaking the binding some how. Is there a way to get the updated value and using $watch at the same time? Thank You!!
Here is the sample code, 
HTML,

```
<input  type=text" ng-model='model1"/>
<input type="text" ng-model='model2"/>  
                                                                                                   and js, 
$scope.$watch('model1',function(){
$scope.model2 = $scope.model1;
  })
```

This does copies the value from first textbox to second but if I update the second textbox, the old value gets saved.

Comment: Can you put up a jsfiddle or plunk with your code?

Comment: it's hard to say what is actually wrong without seeing some code, but it sounds like your `$watch` is incorrectly updating both properties.

Comment: Did you copy your example directly from your code? If so, please get the markup right. You are missing and mixed up some characters: `<input  type="text" ng-model="model1">` and `<input type="text" ng-model="model2">`

Comment: Here is a working fiddle I created for you: http://jsfiddle.net/4epp0u2e/ Please explain what else you are expecting it to do.

Comment: based on the fiddle using an exact replica of the code you posted here working correctly, I believe the problem you are describing must be occurring somewhere else in your code.

Answer (score 0):

I figured out what i was doing wrong. I needed to give a condition when I want to change the value or else it will always change it to model1, since I was basically assigning the value of model1 to model2. A simple null check did the trick,

```
$scope.$watch('model1',function(){
(if ($scope.model2 == null)){
   $scope.model2 = $scope.model1;
  })
}
```

Thank You for all the help everyone.